# Setting up R to compile with gfortran

Tags: r, homebrew, gfortran

I am new to using R on Mac (have always used on Windows). I am wanting to install quantstrat which requires new github based xts version. For the compilation I understand I need gfortran. I have successfully installed gfortran with homebrew on macOS Sierra Version 10.12. However, I am struggling with the final piece of how to make R use gfortran. I understand that there should be 2 steps to this:

Tell R to use gfortran 4.8, create a file called ~/.R/Makevars:

```
mkdir -p ~/.R
touch ~/.R/Makevars
```

Put the following into ~/.R/Makevars:

```
FLIBS=""
F77="gfortran-4.8"
FC="gfortran-4.8"
```

I am a statistician and not a computer guru, and am struggling to know exactly:

1) How I create the 'Makevars' file (?I assume just run that code in the Terminal application)

2) Where I find 'Makevars' once I have created it (ie I presume like Program files on Windows). Is it then just a case of opening that file and pasting the text below?

Comment: You create the file using a text editor, then save it, just as on any other system. The default OS X editor is called TextEdit.

Comment: This question also makes me wonder if you installed  current version of Xcode?

Comment: I'm not sure where your "understanding" might originate, but the authoritative guide to setting up Makevars for current macOS is in TFM (The Fine Manual), section here: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools/ It's possible that you can use a homebrew installed `gfortran` but you're better off asking the person where you got that non-endorsed understanding. Furthermore you should look up your OS specifics about showing hidden files because the default settings for Finder.app are to hide any files (or folders) whose name begins with a period. They're sometime referred to as "dot-files".

Comment: Try executing `vi .R/Makevars` in your home directory.

Comment: Thanks, 42. Indeed, I spent 5 happy hours installing Xcode yesterday...I suspect my systems knowledge is inadequate to deal with this project. Initially I was impressed by macOS's ability to deal with simplified Chinese vs. Windows (English version). But having spent a few days installing programs that on Windows take very little time, I'm changing my mind about the benefits. Your guidelines on the dot files were tantalizingly helpful, but I could not find anything in Library that equated to R, as it might on Windows Program Files, which even I find relatively easy.

Comment: I can download the correct versions of the dev tools that you indicate here, but I still have very little idea as to how to 'connect' them to the R environment to run the new dev xts package, in order to run the blotter package, in order to run quantstrat. I fully acknowledge this is my own shortcoming.